# Is there a native typescript-compiler way to get the inferred type of a Map?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

Given the Typescript declaration:

```
export const map = new Map([
    [1, 'one'],
    [2, 'two'],
]);
```

, I would like to get the inferred type, ie: `Map<number, string>`, using only the native compiler API (Version 5.0.4).

This is the AST in [AST-viewer](https://ts-ast-viewer.com/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wLYEMxwLxzLADucAsjgBQDaAUAJDUCMANHAOQrDsC6LD1AExt2MYhF78eASgDcQA)

It correctly identifies the type of the `<NewExpression>`, but digging in their code shows that they are using a non-native library, "ts-morph".

My logic has been so far:

```
const checker ... //<ts.TypeChecker>
const fileNode ... //<ts.SourceFile>
const fileSymbol = checker.getSymbolAtLocation(fileNode)! //returns <ts.Symbol>
const fileType = checker.getTypeOfSymbol(fileSymbol)! //returns <ts.Type>
const mapSymbol = fileType.getProperty('map')! //returns <ts.Symbol>
console.log(mapSymbol.getName()) //"map"


checker.getTypeOfSymbol(mapSymbol) //returns a <ts.Type>.intrinsicName: 'error'
```

I was expecting to get a valid `<ts.Type>` from the symbol.

I have tried extracting the type from all the ancestors, but have had no success.
I have also tried `<ts.NewExpression>.typeArguments`, but this is `undefined`. The closest I have got is `<ts.NewExpression>.arguments`, but I want to avoid parsing them with a 3rd party or custom type extractor.

I suspect my inexperience with the compiler API is causing me to miss something obvious, but again, maybe not. A steer in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the result of `ts.getPreEmitDiagnostics(program)`. Sounds like there's an error.

The following works for me:

```
const mapType = checker.getTypeOfSymbol(mapSymbol);
console.log(mapType.getSymbol().getName()); // Map
console.log(checker.getTypeArguments(mapType)); // [number, string]
console.log(checker.typeToString(mapType)); // Map<number, string>
```

> This is the AST in [AST-viewer](https://ts-ast-viewer.com/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wLYEMxwLxzLADucAsjgBQDaAUAJDUCMANHAOQrDsC6LD1AExt2MYhF78eASgDcQA)
>
> It correctly identifies the type of the , but digging in their code shows that they are using a non-native library, "ts-morph".

It uses the TypeScript compiler directly. It doesn't use ts-morph on the website at all.

Comment: Thanks a million David!

The results of `ts.getPreEmitDiagnostics(program)` revealed that I had set `noLib = true` in the compiler options. Problem was between seat and keyboard...

Interesting to know about AST-viewer. I see that it is your project. I had incorrectly presumed that the entry point was here: https://github.com/dsherret/ts-ast-viewer/blob/main/scripts/analyzers/TsAnalyzer.ts

Comment: You're welcome! ts-morph is only used to help build the website.

Comment: AST-viewer is a great help. Thanks for that as well.  Just a heads up that the `.git` folder on the repo is very big  (over 1GB)